# making own class for database connection

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, ms-access

I am working on a project that requires msaccess and mysql database, for this I want to make my own class that do the connectivity for msaccess and mysql, everything is ok, but I have struck in ParameterCollection.

here is my code, inside the ParameterCollection
there is no error in set block, but get block giving the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter' to 'MyOleDb.OleDbParameter'

```
public OleDbParameter this[int index]
{
    get
    {
        if (IsMySql())
            return ((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection)this)[index];
        else
            return ((System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection)this)[index];
    }
    set
    {
        if (IsMySql())
            ((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection)this)[index] = value;

        else
            ((System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameterCollection)this)[index] = value;
    }
}
```

any help?

**UPDATE:**

OleDbParameter Class Code, not the fullcode only coversion is here

```
public class OleDbCommand : System.Data.Common.DbCommand, ICloneable, IDbCommand, IDisposable
{
    static public implicit operator MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand(OleDbCommand c)
    {
        return (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand)c;
    }
    static public implicit operator System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(OleDbCommand c)
    {
        return (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand)c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `MyOleDb.OleDbParameter` derive from `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter`? If not, you must write a cast-operator.

Comment: I have write a cast operator for that, I am updating the code for the same.

Comment: Try to create an explicit cast operator and perform your casts explicitly. For testing, I would split things like `return ((MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection)this)[index];
` into more steps to gain abetter overview.

Comment: This link may help you 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c790zwhc.aspx

Comment: Once I was searching, like you, for a solution to this kind of problem. Then I found [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)